# Strange issue with opening app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have LoginActivity where after successful logging I start MainActivity via intent and finish LoginActivity.

I press back button and then open app via icon and It shows me MainActivity but if I open app from recent apps list after pressing back button so I see LoginActivity

I've checked if LoginActivity was destroyed

How can It be?

manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

start MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                startActivity(intent);
                                getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: Can you please add log output. using only finish() will finish your activity.

Comment: @ArthTilva what do U mean? Lifecycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

Why you are adding launchMode, adding this you will be able to get its instance only once. Let default be "Standard", for more information, please have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) say:

> The "standard" and "singleTop" modes differ from each other in just one respect: Every time there's a new intent for a "standard" activity, a new instance of the class is created to respond to that intent. Each instance handles a single intent. Similarly, a new instance of a "singleTop" activity may also be created to handle a new intent. However, if the target task already has an existing instance of the activity at the top of its stack, that instance will receive the new intent (in an `onNewIntent()` call); a new instance is not created.

So, you wouldn't need `singleTask` launch mode. Apart from this, I can't see `<intent-filter>` for your `LoginActivity` as being `MAIN` action and `LAUNCHER` category.